# Android: Copy file from sdcard to app's assets folder programmatically

Tags: android, assets, sd-card

I want to copy file from SD-Card to app's assets  folder in android.Please help me to do it    programmatically.

Comment: No folder in apk is writeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can´t.
The apps assets folder is readable only, so you cant programmatically store (write) your data there.

(Taken from [AssetManager Doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html)):

> This class presents a lower-level API that allows you to **open and read** raw files that have been bundled with the application as a simple stream of bytes.

Also, see [Managing Projects | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html) :

> assets/
>   This is empty. You can use it to **store raw asset files**. Files that you save here **are compiled into an .apk file** as-is, and the original filename is preserved. You can navigate this directory in the same way as a typical file system using URIs and read files as a stream of bytes using the AssetManager. For example, this is a good location for textures and game data.